# How to specify ALL fields in schema for edismax search handler

Tags: java, solr

I have a search handler in Solr with this basic definition (some details omitted for brevity):

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
        <str name="qf">??</str>
        ...
```

I know that I can write a list of fields in the `qf` string, but I want to search all the fields in my schema, including dynamic fields.
I tried this:

```
<str name="qf">*</str>
```

But it didn't work. The search results came back empty. Is there any way to search all the fields in the schema without explicitly enumerating them in the `qf` parameter?

**Update:** I should have mentioned that I don't want to use copy-field because I want to show the user which field matched the search, and show search highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Use the copy field to copy all the fields you want to search on in to a single field.
This should also work for all the static and dynamic fields.
You can specify that single field into your qf parameter.

However, you can't vary the weight and boost for different fields in this approach. 
You can create multiple copy fields and vary the boost accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, dynamic fields can be queried only by its full name

```
qf=myfield_s,myfield1_s
```

Wildcard will not work.